# How can I run 2 virtual hosts on Apache 2.4 where one use port 80 "no ssl" and the other uses port 443 "ssl"?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, php, ssl, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.18 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and PHP 5.6.18.

My Apache server by default have `SSL` turned on. I need to run 2 different sites where one site uses `SSL` and the other one does not.

Here is what I have added to my httpd-vhosts.conf file in attempt to get it to work

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName SERVER1.example.com
   Redirect permanent "C:/phpsites/app1" https://sub1.example.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/phpsites/app2/public"
    ServerName SERVER1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub2.example.com

    SSLEngine Off

    <Directory "C:/phpsites/app2/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

    DocumentRoot "C:/phpsites/app1"
    ServerName SERVER1.example.com
    ServerAlias sub1.example.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile "c:/Apache24/conf/certificate/cert.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/Apache24/conf/certificate/private.key"

    <Directory "C:/phpsites/app1">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

The setting above does not work properly. When I go to `**https**://sub1.example.com` Apache redirects me to the correct site `C:/phpsites/app1`. When I go to `**http**://sub1.example.com` it redirects me to `C:/phpsites/app2/public` but I don't want that to happen. And when I go to `http://sub2.example.com` I get redirected to `**https**://sub1.example.com` for some reason.

I need to direct any user that is looking for
`http://sub1.example.com` or `https://sub1.example.com` to `**https**://sub1.example.com`.

And any users that is looking for `http://sub2.example.com` or `https://sub2.example.com` to go to `**http**://sub2.example.com`

How can I get this to work?

**UPDATED**

Here is what I get when I execute `httpd -D DUMP_VHOSTS`

VirtualHost configuration:

```
*:80 is a NameVirtualHost


default server SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:27)
port 80 namevhost SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:27)

port 80 namevhost SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:34)
 alias sub2.example.com


*:443 is a NameVirtualHost
default server SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:52)
port 443 namevhost SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:52)
 alias sub1.example.com

port 443 namevhost SERVER1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:85)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I go to **http**://sub1.example.com it redirects me to C:/phpsites/app2/public but I don't want that to happen.

It's because you have only one (default) http virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot "C:/phpsites/app2/public"
    ServerAdmin test@example.com
    ServerName sub2.example.com
    ServerAlias sub2.example.com

    SSLEngine Off

    <Directory "C:/phpsites/app2/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

You must add virtualhost for sub1.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName sub1.example.com
   Redirect 301 / https://sub1.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The following line is really strange

```
port 80 namevhost sub1.example.com (C:/Apache24/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:43) alias sub2.example.com
```

Why are you using sub2 as alias in sub1 vhost?

Comment: You must have both http virtualhosts for sub1 and sub2. From the question I can see only one

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added the code you posted to the httpd-vhosts.conf file and restarted apache. But still when I got to https://sub2.example.com or http://sub2.example.com I get directed to https://sub1.example.com instead on http://sub2.example.com

Comment: Add output of the 'apache2ctl -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS' to the question

Comment: I executed the command `httpd -D DUMP_VHOSTS` I think it is the same as what you asked me to do except for windows and I updated the results in my question.

Comment: I updated my question again with the current DUMP_VHOSTS output and the current `httpd-vhosts.conf` content Maybe this one makes more since

Comment: My setting are actually working fine. For some reason Firefox is caching the dns in the browser.

I had to delete my temp file and everything worked like a charm!

It is bothering me and would like to know why would Firefox cache the dns!

I hope this note helps someone in the same boat!